# If database entry is empty show this 'message' in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, message

I am new to rails and was wondering if it were possible to have a default message in the view if the database entry was empty. For example if you had an image you could do this:

```
<%= image_tag "#{post.imge}", :alt => 'Currently no image available'%>
```

So if there wasn't an image link in there it would come up with "Currently no image available" 
But say if you just wanted to show a string so:

```
<%= post.info %>
```

But if post.info were empty I want display an alternative message like "Currently no information available"? I know that 
    <%= post.info, :alt => 'Currently no information available'%>
doesn't work but I can't seem to find any way to do this - probably because it is so easy no one has ever asked the question lol!

I am trying to use the solution below in a helper since I want to use for a few different entries but I can't seem to get it to work - I have added my code below:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def chk_blnk(gogo)
    if gogo.blank?
      "No img"
    else    
      return gogo
    end
  end
end
```

I'm also not sure how to call it in the view when it takes in a variable (post.info) I know that usually you would call it as such:

```
<%= chk_blnk %>
```

I'm sorry if these are really basic questions I have tried searching for answers but again I can't seem to find any.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do this:

```
<%= post.info.blank?? 'No post' : post.info %>
```

or, if you know that `post.info` will be `nil` (rather than an empty string) when there isn't anything in it:

```
<%= post.info || 'No Post' %>
```

or, if you need to include some markup:

```
<% if post.info.blank? %>
    <p>No Post</p>
<% else %>
    <%= post.info %>
<% end %>
```

BTW, the behavior of this:

```
<%= image_tag "#{post.imge}", :alt => 'Currently no image available' %>
```

when there is no image to display is browser dependent: some will give you a broken image icon, some will display the `alt` text, some will display nothing. You are abusing the [`alt` attribute](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Usage/TextAlternatives):

> The preferred means for marking up a text alternative for an `img` element is to use the `alt` attribute to provide a full equivalent for the image, or to provide an `alt` attribute with an empty value (to indicate that the image is purely presentational).

The `alt` text is supposed to be a description of the image suitable for screen readers and other non-graphic interfaces so using *Currently no image available* as the `alt` value doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Hi mu is too short thanks for your reply and the tip about alt I won't use it in this way now. I am trying to use your 2nd solution of the if statement but using .blank? (since it is a string) in helper. But I can't seem to get it to work - I have added it to the post above.

Comment: @user1104150: It was supposed to be `blank?` but my fingers put in `empty?` for some reason. I don't see any changes to the question, are you still working on it?

Comment: @user1104150: You should be able to use `<%= chk_blnk post.info %>`.

Answer (score 2):

Since mu is too short's answer's basically the same, I'll delete mine and give you one other possibility.

If this is always about empty strings or objects that are `nil`, then you could add an `or` method to Ruby's `String` and `NilClass`:

```
class String
  def or(default)
    self.empty? ? default : self
  end
end

class NilClass
  def or(default)
    default
  end
end
```

With this you can do:

```
<%= post.info.or('Currently no information available') %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply I'm not sure where to put this would I put this method into the application controller?

Comment: You can add this code in an initializer. E.g. `config/initializers/extensions.rb`.